# How can I flag a spam/duplicate application at apptivate.ms?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, flags, apptivate.ms

How can I flag a spam/duplicate application on http://www.apptivate.ms? I can't see any option  regarding it.

Now I notify through the Windows 8 developer chat rooms. Is there any way to flag an application there?

Comment: Good call, guess that reporting here is the best option right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For now, stick to reporting them [in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17195/windows-8-developers-chat) or here on MSO. **Don't** flag the user's other SO questions. (We are looking into getting a basic flagging system up on Apptivate. Watch this space for the decision.)

---

### Update:

This has been implemented. Users with at least 15 rep on Stack Overflow will see a "report this app" link below the left sidebar on every app page. Apps that are spam, dupes, or otherwise need staff attention should be flagged using this link.

Comment: Finally, my [Apptivate diamond](http://apptivate.ms/users/106224/boltclock) can be put to use.

Comment: @BoltClock yup, all SO mods are mods on Apptivate, but don't feel obligated to monitor that site for abuse/spam/dupes/whatever. We're on it :)